# Friction in a three pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, rigid-body-dynamics

**Where am I going wrong ?**

[image]

The  coefficient of static and kinetic friction on each surface is 0.5.
We need to find acceleration of all 3 blocks .

**My attempt **

*Assuming that all blocks are moving *

For block A ,

2mg-T=2ma

For B,

2T-0.5mg=0.5ma

For C,

T-0.5mg=ma

On equating for T , the three equations are giving different values of a .

> I believe I am going conceptually wrong .Where did I go wrong ? Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Why are the coefficients of static and kinetic friction the same?

Comment: Well the question says so.

Comment: Probably to make the solution simpler.

Comment: Can you add some more detail as to your attempt at equating for T?

Comment: Value of g is 10m/s^2 . From eq 1,2. a = 70/9 whereas from eq 2,3 , a is -3.33( not possible ) and equating 1,3 gives a as a=5m\

Comment: Why do you assume that block B accelerates at the same rate as blocks A and C? It's not directly connected to the rope, so there's no reason to assume that.

Comment: I have taken acc of A AND C AS 'a' and that of B as '0.5a' for validity of constraint .

Comment: Why do you think you are going *conceptually wrong*? What concept are you confused about?

Comment: How can I determine whether both B and C will move or both will not move or either of the two will move ? Will there be 4 situations ?

Comment: Whether a block moves depends on whether the tension in the string is strong enough to overcome static friction. The tension is the same throughout the string. The accelerations will be different for  each block.

Comment: I found out the accelerations and acc of b is coming to be negative if I have not messed up in the calculations ?

Comment: Maybe you have messed up the calculations ... We cannot tell unless you show what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Your constraint relations are wrong:

If block C moves one step and block B is stationary then block A moves one step too.

If block B moves one step and block C is stationary then block A moves two steps.

Thus,
$$steps_A = 2*steps_B + steps_C$$
$$\implies acc_A = 2*acc_B + acc_C$$

That is the only constraint equation.

Comment: So can all three blocks move together .

Comment: When you solve for the accelerations of the blocks you will find out if they all move or not. But regardless, this is the constraint relation that would be obeyed. It is possible that one of the acc's turn out to be zero. I don't know - I didn't solve it fully.